# flutter: Retrieving multiple document id present inside a collection of firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to get the id of every document in a collection. i tried this code but it return a single document id unlimited times. Can you please suggest a correction or a alternative

```
getrequest() {
    linkref.document(uuid).
    collection("Requests").getDocuments().then((value) async{

      value.documents.forEach((doc) {
        user.add(doc.documentID);
      });},);
  return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext cntxt, int index){
        return Text(user[index]);
      });
}
```

there is a collection  inside a document and inside this collection i have other document. i want to retrieve all documents id

This is screenshot of my firestore

[image]

Comment: please add your firestore a screenshot

Comment: @PeterHaddad please have a look

Comment: u only have one document inside requests

Comment: In future I will have multiple

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you have just one document in firestore. I would suggest you add multiple documents and then test this command.You can use `snapshot` to get multiple documents as suggested by Sandeep using

```
  Firestore.instance
            .collection('Links')
            .document(docID)
            .collection('Requests')
            .snapshots();
```

You can retrieve multiple documents with one request by querying documents in a collection. By default, Cloud Firestore retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID, but you can order and limit the data returned. To retrieve the documents conditionally using `where()` and then use `get`

More can be found in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

To use ListView builder, I would suggest using StreamBuilder something like this:

```
        StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore()
              .collection('homepage')
              .document(widget.user.uid)
              .collection('h')
              .document(todaysDate())
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {

              snapshot.data.data.forEach((index, individualDetail) {
                cardDetails[index] = individualDetail;
              });
            } 
            return cardDetails == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return HomepageCards(
                        user: widget.user,
                        cardDetails:
                            cardDetails[cardDetails.keys.toList()[index]],
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: (cardDetailKeys == null
                        ? 0
                        : cardDetailKeys.length),
                  );
          },
        )
```

This is a snippet from my code but the `StreamBuilder` would look similar for you too.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Firestore.instance
            .collection('Links')
            .document(docID)
            .collection('Requests')
            .snapshots();
```